# Repeat Texture on X axis over 3dObject in ARkit SCNODE - SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I wanted to move the texture over the SCNode in my current scene.

I am currently animating the node but i want the texture to run over the object instead of animating it.

```
let moveup = SCNAction.moveBy(x: 0.01, y: 0, z: 0, duration: 1)
moveup.timingMode = .easeInEaseOut
moveup.speed = CGFloat(20.5)
let moveDown = SCNAction.moveBy(x: -0.01, y: 0, z: 0, duration: 1)
moveDown.timingMode = .easeInEaseOut;
moveDown.speed = CGFloat(20.5)
let moveupSequence = SCNAction.sequence([moveup, moveDown])
print(moveupSequence.duration, moveupSequence.speed)
WaterNode?.runAction(moveupSequence)
```

This is my code for annimating the object. I need to know how can i access the texture and move them to X axis.

Answer (score 0):

There is [contentsTransform](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty/1395388-contentstransform) property of material

```
let action = SCNAction.customAction(duration: 1) { (node, elapsedTime) in
    let c = node.geometry?.materials.first?.diffuse.contentsTransform
    node.geometry?.materials.first?.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation((c?.m41)! + 0.01, (c?.m42)!, (c?.m43)!)
}
```

Comment: what if i wanted to make the material rotate for 90 degree?

Comment: [SCNMatrix4makeRotation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/1409686-scnmatrix4makerotation)

Comment: and you you need to calculate angle for elapsed time